# Android is device power connected without broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to know, is power connected to device or not without broadcast?

In my application I want to get it only on start, so, broadcast receiver is too complicated for my app.

Comment: did you have a look at why it would be complicated. I use it in my applicaiton also to just start a service at the phone restart... can i guide you in the right direction with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out [this method](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) in your application... for better handling the wake up call. without the broadcast receiver. Let me know what you think about it.